# How to identify a turtle

Tags: netlogo

How can identify a turtle so I can ask it to do something.

For example

```
create-turtles 3
set turtle-star one-of turtles

ask turtles[ if  turtle != turtle-star [make-other-turtles-but-turtle-star-do-some-dirty-things]]
```

Is this possible, is like a number or another propertie uniquely in a turte for example:

```
idTurtle
```

Or how can I distinguish a turtle.

I'm thinking I can make an tribute called

```
IsTurtleStar?.
```

But it seems like a waste of memory.

How do you do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

mattsap is correct that you are probably looking for the `who` turtle attribute. However, if you find yourself using the `who` number, you should generally reconsider your approach in NetLogo. It is almost always better to use `agentsets` directly rather than rely on an identifier.

Have a look at this complete model. You will see that I simply refer to the turtle as 'turtle-star' whenever I need it.

```
to testme
  clear-all
  create-turtles 3
  [ setxy random-xcor random-ycor
    set color blue
  ]
  let turtle-star one-of turtles
  ask turtle-star [ set size 3 ]
  ask turtle-star
  [ ask other turtles
    [ set color red
    ]
  ]
end
```

But if you needed turtle-star to exist across procedures you would either need a global variable (and use `set` instead of `let`) to store the turtle (not its who number) or you would need your suggestion of a flag as a `turtles-own` attribute.

Comment: I see, could you explain in your answer why the former is not a good approach in NetLogo?

Comment: `who` numbers are automatically assigned by NetLogo as turtles are created and are not under programmer control. As you develop your model, you may add further turtles and change the order they are created, which makes all your `who` numbers different. And if a turtle dies and you try to refer to it, NetLogo will throw an error. You also end up with code constructions like `ask one-of turtles with [who = <stored number>] [ <do something>]` instead of the much clearer `ask myturtle [<do something>]`.

Comment: Note that you can replace `ask turtle-star [ ask other turtles [ set color red  ]  ]` by `ask [ other turtles ] of turtle-star [ set color red ]`. I prefer the latter, but it's mostly a matter of taste, I think.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are looking to use the turtle's who (turtle variable), which is a unique identifier.

So, in your terms:

```
create-turtles 3
set turtle-star [who] of one-of turtles

ask turtles with [who != turtle-star][make-other-turtles-but-turtle-star-do-some-dirty-things]
```

Comment: Well... yes, but it's probably a bad idea... see [Jen's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55996924/how-to-identify-a-turtle#comment98690628_55997572) about the downsides of using `who` numbers...